# Roaming profile - does it download older files from server?

Tags: samba, roaming-profiles

Long story, but I took a Samba server with roaming profiles out of the network and `fsck` is finding a bunch of errors in files that are synced with roaming profiles. The two users of the system are still using their PCs, so have newer versions of the files in question.

Will the roaming profile system be clever enough not to overwrite the newer files on the client PCs with the possibly corrupted files from the server roaming profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, it did appear to only sync back older files from the outdated server profile. It did, however, sync back files that were deleted on the client PC while the server was away.